# Create indicator

Tags: r, matrix, indicator

I would like to create a numeric indicator for a matrix such that for each unique element in one variable, it creates a sequence of the length based on the element in another variable. For example:

```
frame<- data.frame(x = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), y = c(3,3,3,2,2))
frame
  x y
1 a 3
2 a 3
3 a 3
4 b 2
5 b 2
```

The indicator, z, should look like this:

```
  x y z
1 a 3 1
2 a 3 2
3 a 3 3
4 b 2 1
5 b 2 2
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this an indicator for x, for y or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No `ave`?

```
frame$z <- with(frame, ave(y,x,FUN=seq_along) )
frame

#  x y z
#1 a 3 1
#2 a 3 2
#3 a 3 3
#4 b 2 1
#5 b 2 2
```

A `data.table` version could be something like below (thanks to @mnel):

```
#library(data.table)
#frame <- as.data.table(frame)
frame[,z := seq_len(.N), by=x]
```

My original thought was to use:

```
frame[,z := .SD[,.I], by=x]
```

where `.SD` refers to each subset of the `data.table` split `by` `x`. `.I` returns the row numbers for an entire `data.table`. So, `.SD[,.I]` returns the row numbers within each group. Although, as @mnel points out, this is inefficient compared to the other method as the entire `.SD` needs to be loaded into memory for each group to run this calculation.

Comment: Don't do `.SD[,.I]`, use `z := seq_len(.N)`. For cases where `.SD` is large, the latter will be more memory (and time) efficient

Comment: Hmm the `[,.I]` only works with `.SD` not any arbitrary set of columns. I suspect there is some merging underlying the `.SD` magic.

Comment: @ScottRitchie  The reason `.SD[,.I]` works is because in this `.I` is scoped within `.SD`, see  `frame[, c('z1','z2') := list(.I,.SD[,.I]),by=x]` for example

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
frame$z <- unlist(lapply(rle(as.numeric(frame[, "x"]))$lengths, seq_len))
```

Comment: `sequence(rle(as.numeric(frame$x))$lengths)` seems more direct to me. One possible problem (or advantage, depending on what the OP wants) with the `rle` approach is that the data need to be sorted first or the sequence would be reset every time the values in "x" change.

Comment: @Ananda I assumed that was actually what the OP wanted but this may not be the case.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
frame %.%
  group_by(x) %.%
  mutate(z = seq_along(y))
```

Comment: Well played sir well played +1

Comment: @TylerRinker, not that well.. Two other solutions required data to be ordered by `x`

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `data.frame` on `x`, and generate a new id column based on that:

```
> frame$z <- unlist(lapply(split(frame, frame$x), function(x) 1:nrow(x)))
> frame
  x y z
1 a 3 1
2 a 3 2
3 a 3 3
4 b 2 1
5 b 2 2
```

Or even more simply using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
frame <- data.table(frame)[,z:=1:nrow(.SD),by=x]
```

Comment: Instead of `1:nrow(.SD)` you could use `.N` (`data.table(frame)[,z:=sequence(.N),by=x]`)

Comment: Referencing `.SD` will load the entire `.SD` into the memory. Use `z:=seq_len(.N)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this where `x` is the column by which grouping is to be done and `y` is any numeric column.  if there are no numeric columns use `seq_along(x)`, say, in place of `y`:

```
transform(frame, z = ave(y, x, FUN = seq_along))
```

Comment: Beat you to that one... :-)

Comment: Yes, I was also surprised that no one had suggested `ave` even after a few minutes.